# Return of array from a function in c

Tags: c, arrays

I have a little confusion. Please look into following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void display (int *j, int *k);

int main()
{
    int num1[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int num2[5];
    int i;
    display (num1,num2);
    for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
        printf("%d,", num2[i]);
    return 0;
}

void display (int *j, int *k)
{
    int l;  
    for (l=0;l<=4;l++)
    {
        k=j;
        printf("%d,", *k);
        j++;
        k++;        
    }

}
```

In this `printf("%d,", num2[i]);` is not giving the array. But it works when we put `*k=*j;` in the function. Can you please explain why ? Thanks.

Comment: To whomever is trying to edit this post: fixing indention is fine, changing the coding style to suit your own personal preference is not, that is to be regarded as changing the meaning of the code.

Answer (score 1):

`k=j` assigns the pointer `k` to the value (address pointed to) of pointer `j`.  This toggles which array (`num1` or `num2`) `k` points to but doesn't change the value of any array element.

`*k=*j` sets the array element that `k` points to to the value of the array element `j` points to.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not initialized the array `num2` nor copy it from `num1`.

Answer (score 0):

`*k = *j` copies the content of the "cell" `j` points to to the cell `k` points to. On the contrary, `k = j` makes `k` point to where `j` points. If you think about this, `k = j` is wrong, as you do not alter the content of your arrays, but rather just change the local variable `k`. Hence in your example, the print statement inside `display` does, in fact, not print `num2`, but `num1` (as at the point of the print statement, `k` points to the same location as `j` does, which is an element of `num1`).

Answer (score 0):

The statement `k = j;` which means "assign the value stored in `j` as the value of `k`", merely copy the value stored in `j` to `k`. It does nothing on the arrays, just the pointer `k` points to the address pointed to by `j`. The assignment and increments effects only local variable `j` and `k`, nothing else.

When you write `*k = *j;`, it essentially means "assign the content of address `j` to address `k`", which does the copying, and incrementing `j` and `k` points them to the next array element.

Comment: Thank you all, I need to more involve beacause I can't understand fully your answers. Thanks.